# Write data to DynamoDB with Composite Primary Key

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have trouble with writing data using Composite Primary Key to DynamoDB. I have created a DynamoDB table called TestTable with a primary and a sort key. Here is my AWS Lambda function:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
myDocumentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
var params ={
    TableName: 'TestTable',
    Item: {
    'Username': event.Username, \\ Primary Key
    'ProductID' : event.ProductID, \\ Sort Key
    'Price': event.Price
  }
};

const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify('Item Added'),
};

myDocumentClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
}); 
}
```

The problem is that when I tested on Postman with this data

```
{
 "Username": "Kane",
 "ProductID": 34,
 "Price": 43,
}
```

it works fine. However, when I ran my React App with this code

```
const  handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios.post('API-URL',
        {Username:`Hii`, ProductID:`${id}`, Price:`${price}`} \\ Problem is here
    );
 }
```

, it didn't write data to the table. I think the problem is at this line

```
{Username:`Hii`, ProductID:`${id}`, Price:`${price}`}
```

Can someone help me? I've tried to figure it out about five hours, but got nothing. Thank you so much.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i got no error, but all the data cannot be written to the table.

Comment: Have you tried seding the data without converting ProductId and Price to string? `{Username:'Hii', ProductID: id, Price: price}`

Comment: Woa~~!! That's magic. I fixed the issue. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!